# redux state automatically change when variable change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

my code is

`const state = getState();
var drag_trips = state.sale.drag_trips;
drag_trips[0].deliveries.push(delivery);`

when I change variable drag_trips it automatically changes state without dispatching.

i want to store and update state and at the end i will store it in another state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't `mutate` the state. State should be `immutable` and should be always computed through [redux reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html).

You should only read from the state at this point.

In your case dispatching a `redux action` with `delivery` as payload, and catching it in `reducer` by adding it to the state would be the way to go.

See [todo](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) example.

Answer (score 0):

This is because objects are mutable. When you `.push` on the array, you are changing the actual state from `getState()`, instead of modifying a copy.

Get a *copy* of an array by doing `var drag_trips = state.sale.drag_trips.slice()`

Comment: var drag_trips = state.sale.drag_trips.slice()  not working.

Comment: when I change copy of  drag_trips created using .slice() still it change state directly instead of changing copied array